# Continuous function that has limit at infinity is uniformly continuous (another viewpoint)

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I know how to prove that, given a continuous $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim _ {x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous (by means of taking a big enough compact set etc)

But I had a different idea...

If I compactified $[0,\infty)$ by adjointing $\infty$, and defining $f(\infty)=L$, I would have a continuous function on a compact set... hence, a uniformly continuous function. But this is not yet right, since I have no metric in $[0,\infty]$ a priori. I could infuse a metric on the space (for example, using the fact that this space is regular and has countable basis), but I don't have a way to relate the metrics from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\infty]$ in order to "preserve" uniform continuity.

Can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an explicit approach that suggests a solution.

Define $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} f( \tan ({\pi \over 2} x)), & x \in [0, 1) \\
L, & x=1 \end{cases}$. Then $\phi$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,1]$,
hence uniformly continuous.

Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|< \delta$, then $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)| < \epsilon$.

Now suppose $|a-b|<\delta$. Then $|\arctan a - \arctan b| \le |a-b| < \delta$, and so
$|f(a)-f(b)| = |\phi(\arctan a) - \phi(\arctan b)| < \epsilon$, hence $f$ is
uniformly continuous.

Comment: Nice, upvoted. But this uses strongly the $\tan$ function. I'm looking, if possible, for a more topological solution. If not possible, I would like a good argument explaining why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Well, you need a definition of uniform continuity in $[0,\infty]$. The usual way is via a metric that is compatible with the 'compactified' topology, so use $d(x,y) = |\arctan x -\arctan y|$, with $d(x,\infty)={\pi \over 2}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Then it has to be true even if $L= \infty$ right?

Comment: @MeetPatel no. Try $f(x) = x^2$.