# Uniformly continuous at infinity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Suppose that there exists $L \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$.

I usually do fine however I am stuck at implementing my idea. I thought to assume the opposite*, then choose $\frac\varepsilon2$ at the limit definition where the epsilon is given by the assumption*. What do I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Please write down explicitely what you mean by  "assume the opposite*, then choose ε/2
 at the limit definition where the epsilon is given by the assumption*."

Comment: This is pretty obvious if you try to understand what I ask instead of looking after what I did not provide. '

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1011471/27978

Comment: My question was aimed to help you. I did try to understand but your writing was too allusive. If you don't make the effort to present your question *and attempt* clearly, we cannot help you efficiently, despite all our goodwill and expertise. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this by 'splitting' the function. Because there is a limit, we see that:

There exists an $N$ such that $x\geq N\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

This means that $|f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})|<\epsilon$ for any $x_{1},x_{2}\geq N$.

Thus on [N,$\infty$) it follows directly that the function is uniformly continuous: whichever $\delta$ you choose, the difference between two function values is always less than $\epsilon$. Thus the 'second half' of the function is uniformly continuous.

The 'first half' of the function is then defined on the closed interval $[0,N]$. It follows from a theorem that a continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: This is what I did however I dont see why this corresponds the definition of uniform continuity. E.g, given a smaller epsilon, the interval $[N,\infty)$ might not satisfy that condition anymore. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is important to look at the definition of the limit. For every $\epsilon$ there exists an $N$ such that $x>N\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. If you take a smaller epsilon, then there is a different $N$ such that the implication still holds. Intuitively: for a smaller epsilon you need a bigger $N$, but that is allowed.

Comment: But if you give me some epsilon and I give you N, how does that imply $f$ is uniformly continuous at $[N, \infty)$

Comment: @UnrulyTank This is roughly the idea but there is a small hole in your racket. To locate it, and for a complete and rigorous proof, look at the careful *question and* answer in [the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684116) I provided.

Comment: @AnneBauval the idea isnt similar to what he suggested

Comment: Read more carefully the *whole* post.